# Conditions SQL executions

Tags: sql

I am search for a method that will let me execute one part of the query if it is true and the other part when it is false

For example:

I have a logging table

```
ID | OSUSER | LOG_MSG      | LOG_DATE
----------------------------------------
1  | ADM    | lOGIN SUCCES | 21-11-2018
```

When ADM logs in then I want to execute

`Select OSUSER, LOG_DATE from LOG`

But when Someone else logs in then I want to add LOG_MSG to the query

My question: is this obtainable in sql?

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Which db it is? oracle or sqlserver?

Answer (score 1):

A SQL query returns a fixed set of columns. So, you could only do what you want with dynamic SQL or multiple queries.

However, you can mask the message for "ADM":

```
select l.OSUSER, l.LOG_DATE,
       (CASE WHEN l.OSUSER <> 'ADM' THEN LOG_MSG END) as LOG_MSG
from LOG l;
```

Answer (score 0):

what about case when like below

```
select ID, case when OSUSER='ADM' then OSUSER else LOG_MSG end,LOG_DATE
from LOG
```